# How to represent a general operator on the unit interval as an integral operator?

Tags: operator-theory

I am interested in studying operators of the form $F: I^I \to I^I$, where $I = [0, 1]$ is the unit interval and $I^I$ is the space of functions from $I$ to $I$. I want to find a way to represent any such operator as an integral operator, that is, as

$$F(x)(t) = \int_0^1 M(t, \tau) \cdot x(\tau) d\tau$$

where $M: I \times I \to \mathbb{R}$ is some function that acts as a kernel. My motivation for this is to generalize the idea of representing finite-dimensional operators as matrix multiplication to the infinite-dimensional case.

My question is: what are the limitations of this approach? What kind of conditions do I need to impose on $M$ or $F$ to ensure that such a representation exists and is unique? Are there any examples of operators that cannot be represented in this way? How can I find or construct the kernel function $M$ for a given operator $F$?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Escher and welcome to the Mathematics Stack Exchange. You should provide your question with a bit of context and show your efforts towards solution: perhaps you can have a look at the ["how to ask a good answer" guidelines(Hi Escher and welcome to the Mathematics Stack Exchange. You should provide your question with ).